# hadoop yarn resource management

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2

I have a Hadoop cluster with 10 nodes. Out of the 10 nodes, on 3 of them, HBase is deployed. There are two applications sharing the cluster.
Application 1 writes and reads data from hadoop HDFs. Application 2 stores data into HBase. Is there a way in yarn to ensure that hadoop M/R jobs launched
by application 1 do not use the slots on Hbase nodes? I want  only the Hbase M/R jobs launched by application 2 to use the HBase nodes.
This is needed to ensure enough resources  are available for application 2 so that the HBase scans are very fast.

Any suggestions on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

if you run HBase and your applications on Yarn, the application masters (of HBase itself and the MR Jobs) can request the maximum of available resources on the data nodes.

Are you aware of the hortonworks project [Hoya](http://hortonworks.com/blog/introducing-hoya-hbase-on-yarn/) = HBase on Yarn ?

Especially one of the features is:

> Run MR jobs while maintaining HBase’s low latency SLAs

Comment: does this mean we have to implement our own application master where we can specify the hostnames?

Comment: If Hbase's Application Masters are configured to use all of the nodes ressources no other applications should be able to get resources on those nodes from the resource manager.